# Opencart 2.0.x.x hide menu

Tags: menu, themes, opencart, journal

I have small problem with opencart 2.0.3.1. I use Journal theme and I want my main page to not show main menu. I want to create something like "welcome" page where I don't want to show a menu.

I'm not sure where to look; I have custom home page where I redirected all modules from journal to my new "main page" but I couldn't do the same with menu.

I tried looking on structure of the page but I don't entirely understand it. I was used to joomla structure before.
Also I tried to find line that call for menu on exact page but could´t find it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the homepage template (home.tpl) add custom css along the lines of

```
<style>
#menu {
      display:none;
}
<style>
```

This will hide the menu (if it has the id menu) just on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much it did nothing but i change the code to corespond with my template to:

```
<style>
div#sticky-wrapper {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

and now its working you realy helped me thank you again